# THREE.JS Make indexed buffer geometry from geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

I want to make indexed buffer geometry from geometry to load it in OpenGL ES2, I used the following code and it success to create the geometry similar to the original but when applying the texture some faces is not rendered correctly

```
var g = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var fposition = new Float32Array(geometry.vertices.length * 3);
var fnormals = new Float32Array(geometry.vertices.length * 3);
var fcolors = new Float32Array(geometry.vertices.length * 3);
var fuvs = new Float32Array(geometry.vertices.length * 2);
var findexes = new Uint16Array(geometry.faces.length * 3);

var vi = [];
var k = 0;
var ni = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
    fposition[i * 3] = (geometry.vertices[i].x);
    fposition[i * 3 + 1] = (geometry.vertices[i].y);
    fposition[i * 3 + 2] = (geometry.vertices[i].z);

    fcolors[i * 3] = 1;
    fcolors[i * 3 + 1] = 1;
    fcolors[i * 3 + 2] = 1;
}
for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
    findexes[i * 3] = (geometry.faces[i].a);
    findexes[(i * 3) + 1] = (geometry.faces[i].b);
    findexes[(i * 3) + 2] = (geometry.faces[i].c);

    if (vi.indexOf(geometry.faces[i].a) === -1) {
        fuvs[k] = (geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i][0].x);
        fuvs[k + 1] = (geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i][0].y);

        fnormals[ni] = (geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[0].x);
        fnormals[ni + 1] = (geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[0].y);
        fnormals[ni + 2] = (geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[0].z);

        vi.push(geometry.faces[i].a);
        k += 2;
        ni += 3
    }
    if (vi.indexOf(geometry.faces[i].b) === -1) {
        fuvs[k] = (geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i][1].x);
        fuvs[k + 1] = (geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i][1].y);

        fnormals[ni] = (geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[1].x);
        fnormals[ni + 1] = (geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[1].y);
        fnormals[ni + 2] = (geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[1].z);

        vi.push(geometry.faces[i].b);
        k += 2;
        ni += 3;
    }
    if (vi.indexOf(geometry.faces[i].c) === -1) {
        fuvs[k] = (geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i][2].x);
        fuvs[k + 1] = (geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i][2].y);

        fnormals[ni] = (geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[2].x);
        fnormals[ni + 1] = (geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[2].y);
        fnormals[ni + 2] = (geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[2].z);

        vi.push(geometry.faces[i].c);
        k += 2;
        ni += 3;
    }
}

var position = new THREE.BufferAttribute(fposition, 3);
var index = new THREE.BufferAttribute(findexes, 1);
var color = new THREE.BufferAttribute(fcolors, 3);
var normal = new THREE.BufferAttribute(fnormals, 3);
var uv = new THREE.BufferAttribute(fuvs, 2);

g.addAttribute("position", position);
g.addAttribute("color", color);
g.addAttribute("uv", uv);
g.addAttribute("normal", normal);
g.setIndex(index);
g.getAttribute("uv").needsUpdate = true;
```

the right model is the correct one, Notice the line in the center of the model
[image: Notice the line in the center of the model]

Comment: What does *"some faces is not rendered correctly"* mean? Can you provide a screenshot of the expected result vs the current result?

Comment: I added the screenshot

Comment: @mrdoob can you help me?

Comment: You are going to have to debug your code yourself. Start by applying it to `THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 )`. Or just use `BufferGeometry.setFromGeometry( geometry )` and use non-indexed.

Comment: I do, the code works well with complicated geometries rather than simple ones, all my problem with drawing the texture on some faces as shown in the image attached, I have to make it indexed to reduce the data transfer between server and the android OpenGL client

Comment: Any news on this ?
I got the buffergeometry merge to work, but not the uvs...